# References for Poisson's equation with datum in weighted $L^2$ space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, regularity-theory-of-pdes, poissons-equation

I'm trying to figure out some basic properties of the following problem.

Fix the ball $B_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and let us look at
\begin{cases}
\hfill -\Delta u = g\,, \qquad &x\in B_1\,,\\
\hfill u=0\,, \qquad &x\in \partial B_1\,,
\end{cases}
with $g$ such that $|x|^2 g(x)$ is in $L^2$ (equivalently, $g\in L^2(B_1, |x|^4\mathcal{L}^2)$).

I would expect that a solution $u$ is such that $|x|\nabla u \in L^2$, but this does not seem immediate to prove.

Can you point me to some references (maybe even some more general theory, with weigths $|x|^p$ and in general bounded Lipschitz domains $\Omega$, possibly in $\mathbb{R}^N$)?

Comment: *Hint*: Look at (weighted, local) Sobolev interpolation inequalities, plus you probably want to recall elliptic estimates.

Comment: you could multiply the by |x|^2, then by a test function, then integrate by parts.